# Spring server doesn't start with actuator dependency

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, tomcat9

If I add spring boot actuator dependency my server doesn't start. I get the following error:

```
    SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor [tomcat path\conf\Catalina\localhost\test.xml]
            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:692)
                    
...
            Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/agromarket]]
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
                    ... 37 more
            Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext cannot be cast to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext
                    at rs.navigator.alexandar.sync.WebAppInitializer.onStartup(WebAppInitializer.java:34)
                    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
```

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Any ideas why? From my knowledge even if the versions aren't compatible the server should still be able to start.

Edit:
My WebAppInitializer:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println(("------------------ Sync context initialized and application started ------------------"));
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        // ctx.register(ServletContextListener.class);

//      ctx.register(SecurityConfiguration.class);
//      ctx.register(SpringFoxConfig.class);
//      ctx.register(WebMvcConfigure.class);
//      ctx.register(JPAConfiguration.class);
//      ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
        
        // Reconfigure log4j
//      ServletContext sctx = ctx.getServletContext();
        System.setProperty("logFilename", servletContext.getContextPath().substring(1));
        org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext sctxLog =
                (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
            sctxLog.reconfigure();
            
        //Dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("mvc-dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Error stack after adding @EnableAutoConfiguration
[image]

Comment: Can you add the code of your `WebAppInitializer`?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz just did, hope it hleps.

Comment: I just checked, server doesn't start when I add spring-boot-starter-web dependency too.

Comment: Why do you need `sctxLog.reconfigure()`? Casting to a specific implementation of an interface is always risky: in your case the implementation class used changed, hence the `ClassCastException`..

Comment: That part I didn't write myself, should I try to change it?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I commented it out. Server starts but I don't get the actuator endpoint now.

Comment: Do you have a class that extends [`SpringBootServletInitializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/support/SpringBootServletInitializer.html)? It is (almost) required to start a Spring Boot application under Tomcat.

Comment: I do, but endpoint still doesn't show up.

Comment: Please, add the class to your question. You can also try removing `WebAppInitializer`, since it performs almost the same role as a `SpringBootServletInitializer`.

Comment: I basically just extended WebAppInitializer with SpringBootServletInitializer, thinking it would just add the needed functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want benefit from the automatic features of Spring Boot, your `@Configuration` class must be annotated with [`@EnableAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html).

Since the auto-configuration already creates a `DispatcherServlet` bound to `/`, you can safely change your `WebAppInitializer` class to:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebAppInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

}
```

Comment: I already tried adding @EnableAutoConfiguration, but my server doesn't start after adding it.

Comment: You need `@EnableAutoConfiguration` + `@Configuration`: the [`SpringBootApplication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) implies both.

Comment: I added both, same result.

Comment: What does _"my server doesn't start"_ mean? Can you update your question with the error in the log and the updated version of your `WebAppInitializer` class (if it is different from the one in my answer).

Comment: I added the error (had to do it as a picture since stackoverflow doesn't allow more code without me writing a lot of text myself). Anyway the WebAppInitializer is the same as the one I previously posted expect it now extends SpringBootServletInitializer and has an @SpringBootApplication annotation.

Comment: Btw thanks for the patients up until now.

Comment: Nvm It was just a problem with bad dependencies. Server starts up normally now, still not actuator endpoint though, but this problem seems resolved. Thank you.

Comment: Remember that only `/actuator/health` is exposed through HTTP by default (cf. [exposing endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.exposing)).

Comment: I tried exposing endpoints through literally all of the ways I found on the internet. Just to check, right now spring boot is fully integrated with my project right?

Comment: @aratata Do you remember which dependency was causing issues to start the Spring Server ?